# pupulating grid view using list of() using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a Class called BOOK where the information is there and I wanted to populate the information of this book in a datagrid of the class DELETE_BOOKS using list of() or array. but when I tried to run the code, information did not show up.please tell me if there's something wrong in the code. fyi, I'm not good in programming.
here's my code:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class CONNECTION
    Protected con As New MySqlConnection
    Protected da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Protected ds As New DataSet
    Protected cmds As New MySqlCommand
    Protected dr As MySqlDataReader
    Protected dbcon, sql As String
    Protected dt As DataTable

    Public Sub New()
        con = New MySqlConnection
    End Sub
    Public Sub opendb()
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;User Id=root;database=school_library"
        con.Open()
    End Sub
    Public Sub closedb()
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class DELETE_BOOKS
    Private Sub DELETE_BOOKS_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'lload()
        Dim bk As New List(Of BOOK)
        bindgrid(bk)
    End Sub
    Private Sub bindgrid(ByVal bk As List(Of BOOK))
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bk
    End Sub
```

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class BOOK
    Inherits CONNECTION

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Private titles As String
    Private authors As String
    Private pubs As String
    Private cond As String
    Private cats As String
    'Private quan As Integer
    Private avail_quan As Integer
    Private shelfinfo As Integer
    Private phys As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    'Public Sub New(titles As String, authors As String, pubs As String, cond As String, cats As String, quan As Integer, avail_quan As Integer, shelfinfo As Integer, phys As String)
    Public Sub New(titles As String, authors As String, pubs As String, cond As String, cats As String, avail_quan As Integer, shelfinfo As Integer, phys As String)
        Me.titles = titles
        Me.authors = authors
        Me.pubs = pubs
        Me.cond = cond
        Me.cats = cats
        'Me.quan = quan
        Me.avail_quan = avail_quan
        Me.shelfinfo = shelfinfo
        Me.phys = phys
    End Sub

        Public Function populatedata() As List(Of BOOK)

        Try
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT *FROM books", con)
            opendb()
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Dim bk As New List(Of BOOK)

            While dr.Read
                bk.Add(New BOOK)
                bk((bk.Count - 1)).titles = dr("Title").ToString
                bk((bk.Count - 1)).authors = dr("Author").ToString
                bk((bk.Count - 1)).pubs = dr("Publisher").ToString
                bk((bk.Count - 1)).cond = dr("Condition").ToString
                bk((bk.Count - 1)).cats = dr("Category").ToString
                bk((bk.Count - 1)).avail_quan = dr("Quantity").ToString
                bk((bk.Count - 1)).shelfinfo = dr("Shelf Info").ToString
                bk((bk.Count - 1)).phys = dr("Physical Status").ToString
            End While
            con.Close()
            Return bk
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: well yes I needed to use list of() or just an array, as per the requirement given by professor. but I don't know how to it in a right way. or perhaps do you have an idea when populating it using array ? or is using the list of() impossible when populating it in datagrid? thank you.

Comment: can you assist me how ? do I need to do it like this is Class BOOK, I mean do I need to use PUBLIC FUNCTION, say for example for title ?

Comment: from what I understood from your requirement is: you have a class named book that you will use to get information about your books. You will need to be able to add or remove book and populate the books in the library.  But when you run your code you aren't getting the result you wanted?  Did I got your question right?

Comment: no, no, i mean, i wanted to populate the book information in the datagrid inside the form DELETE_BOOK. no deleting just populate in datagrid.